# jQuery .live('click', function() {}); doesn't work for iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

I have some jQuery functions which update some numbers when new values are selected in a `<SELECT>` field. The `<SELECT>` items are added dynamically by the user, so these functions use the .live() function. Everything goes as planned in Mozilla, Chrome, and IE8, but when I try to access the page on my iPad the numbers are no longer being updated accordingly. I have to **click** the `<SELECT>` field a **second time** for the numbers to update. Here is one of my functions:

```
    // Update subtotal when .months is changed
    $(".months").live('click',function(){

        var pid = this.id.replace("months", "");
        var price = document.getElementById('row' + pid).className;
        updateSubtotal(pid, price);

    });
```

All of the functions are contained within the `document.ready()` block. I've tried 'click change' and just 'change' as well, but they have issues in some other browsers.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Does the same problem occur if using the *non-live* `click` handler? `live` requires event bubbling, so something could be slightly amiss...

Comment: I originally was using `.click` and it wasn't working because the elements triggering the function did not exist when the page is first loaded. I was told to use `.live` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPad and select elements don't play very nice. You will need to bind to **blur** if you need the selected value to do anything.

Try something like this ( *.months* should be your select element ):

```
// Update subtotal when .months is changed
$(".months").on('blur', function(){

    var pid = this.id.replace("months", "");
    var price = document.getElementById('row' + pid).className;
    updateSubtotal(pid, price);

   });
```

**EDIT**
Try this:

```
// Update subtotal when .months is changed
$(document).on('blur|click', ".months", function(){
    var pid = this.id.replace("months", "");
    var price = document.getElementById('row' + pid).className;
    updateSubtotal(pid, price);
    });
```

The nice thing about **on()** is that you can attach it to an element and delegate from there. Since your *$(document)* will always be there it can also catch elements you add dynamically to the page and which are not there from the beginning. Since your original code used *live* I
expect the element to by loaded or generated dynamically. In that case in order to bind an event to it using *on()* you have to bind to the *document* and *delegate* to whatever *.months* is coming.

Comment: I tried this with the function still inside the `document.ready()` block and it froze all other JavaScript functions in the block. I moved it outside the block and everything else worked again, except for this function. This was tested in Chrome. I didn't try the iPad because it doesn't do me any good if it fails on something like Chrome anyway.

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Turns out I'm running a very old version (1.3). I am new to jQuery and I'm updating old code that someone else wrote, so that didn't even occur to me. I'm downloading 1.7 now. I also just came across this: http://www.danwellman.co.uk/fixing-jquery-click-events-for-the-ipad/

Comment: ok. I was using on(), which is new in Jquery 1.7 and should be used to replace live() and bind(), because it's supposedly faster.

Comment: @Kevin_TA - as per your link. This is possible of course although everybody says, userAgent sniffing should be avoided. If you had used my snippet and wanted a solution for iOS and other platforms it would have boiled down to something similar = using something to check for iPad (I'm usually using $.support.touch although this is more general than iPad) and then bind to this event if iPad and that event if everybody else. I see you are on good way tough!

Comment: I see. I am not having any luck with the .on('blur' that you suggested even with my jQuery updated to 1.7. .on('click' isn't working either so it is a problem with .on()

Answer (score 0):

If you add an empty onclick="" to the div (or span, or anything), it works.... 
I dont't know why :)